# "Больше раз, чем" или "большее число раз, чем"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Как лучше сказать:
*Сегодняшнее затмение было сфотографировано **больше раз**, чем предыдущее.*
Или:
*Сегодняшнее затмение было сфотографировано **большее число/количество раз**, чем предыдущее.*

Comment: Лучше сказать "чаще". Учительница в моей школе всегда повторяла: не знаете, как правильно использовать слово/выражение - замените его тем словом/выражением, в котором уверены.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

РАЗ II. в зн. сущ. 1. (обычно со сл., обозначающими количество). Указывает на кратность действия.

Выбираем краткий вариант: Сегодняшнее затмение было сфотографировано **больше раз, чем предыдущее.**

Но второй вариант также встречается. Если судить по частотности этих выражений, то (1) больше раз, (2) большее число раз. "Количество раз" обычно  используется в выражениях вида "бесчисленное количество раз".

Примеры:

Из заднего кармана он добыл свой большой и, как он выражался, «боевой» портсигар и, удрученно кивая, постучал несколько раз, **больше раз, чем обычно**, папиросой о крышку. [В. В. Набоков. Случай из жизни (1935)]

В результате стоимость таким образом изготовленного инструмента по сравнению с изготовленным на специальном заводе массовым способом обходится в цеху, я думаю, не меньше чем в 10, а скорее всего в еще **большее число раз** дороже. [П. Л. Капица. Отчеты (1939-1941) // «Химия и жизнь», 1985]

Дузе, Ермолова, Сальвини куда **большее число раз**, чем я, сыграли свои коронные роли. [К. С. Станиславский. Моя жизнь в искусстве (1925-1928)]

Answer (score -1):

Второй вариант - большее количество раз.